# R function to filter a vector of sentences with a vector of words

Tags: r, vector

I am stuck with trying to extract sentences from vectors. The picture with the correct formatting is attached. Thank you in advance!

eg:

```
Vector1    Vector2
One        One day, it was sunny| There was no rain| There was One dollar on the floor
Two        Two day, it was rainy| There was no sun
Three      There was Three dollars on the floor| It was wet| Three of ants on floor|
```

Answer:

```
Key        Sentence1                              Sentence2                           Sentence3
One        One day, it was sunny                  There was One dollar on the floor
Two        Two day, it was rainy
Three      There was Three dollars on the floor   Three of ants on floor
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in long format by splitting `Vector2` on `"|"`, keep only those rows that have `Vector1` present in them and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Vector2, sep = '\\|\\s*') %>%
  filter(stringr::str_detect(Vector2, paste0('\\b', Vector1, '\\b'))) %>%
  group_by(Vector1) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('Sentence', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = Vector2)

# Vector1 Sentence1                            Sentence2                        
#  <chr>   <chr>                                <chr>                            
#1 One     One day, it was sunny                There was One dollar on the floor
#2 Two     Two day, it was rainy                NA                               
#3 Three   There was Three dollars on the floor Three of ants on floor
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Vector1 = c("One", "Two", "Three"), 
Vector2 = c("One day, it was sunny| There was no rain| There was One dollar on the floor",
"Two day, it was rainy| There was no sun", 
"There was Three dollars on the floor| It was wet| Three of ants on floor"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for the ans, tried it but it doesnt split Vector2. according to the |

Comment: What does it return then? Any error ? Did you assign the output to a new object `df1 <- df %>% separate_rows....rest of the code...` ? If it still doesn't work can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset using `dput(head(df))`  where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: @Volatile Did you check this? Did it work? If not, please add data using `dput` for first few rows as shown above. I am sure it's a small change.